# WebDriver error: UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i click a button in Selenium WebDriver I get the following error, using Firefox 43 and Selenium 2.47.1:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at testDay1.main(testDay1.java:8)
```

Comment: You need to use a newer version of java that supports version 51.0 .class files - try with either java 7 or 8 for support of that version

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8 still facing this issue

Comment: Make sure that the selenium testrunner isn't being launched with a different java version, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i found the solution actually i was not set the Compiler Compliance level from 1.5 to 1.7.